# I'm building docker image automatically after a git commit but it is hitting an ERROR

Tags: git, github, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've added my Access token generated from Docker Hub and added it to the github new repo secrets and the that tag name add to the yaml workflow file that I've provided below
it is building the image but in the time of pushing to docker hub it is failing and the ERROR is like:

ERROR: failed to solve: failed to push hemanthad23/portfolio: failed to authorize: failed to fetch oauth token: unexpected status from GET request to https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Ahemanthad23%2Fportfolio%3Apull%2Cpush&service=registry.docker.io: 401 Unauthorized
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

I've e mentioned my user name correct
**Image name:** hemanthad23/portfolio

**.yaml file:**

```
name: Build and Push Docker Image

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main  # Replace with your default branch name
      

jobs:
  build-and-push:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up Docker Buildx
      uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1

    - name: Build Docker image
      run: |
        docker buildx create --use
        docker buildx build --tag hemanthad23/portfolio --push .

    env:
      DOCKER_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.dockerkey }}  # Set this secret in your repository settings
      DOCKER_USERNAME: myusername # Your Docker Hub username
```

`